# Electric Field and Calculus: What is the physical significance of infinitesimal $dA$ in the equation of Gauss's Theorem?

Tags: electrostatics, integration, calculus

In many equations we see infinitesimals $dA$, $dS$, $dx$ and so on.
What is is the physical significance of these?
Someone told me it signifies a small entity.
For example,in case of $dA$ it signifies a small area, in case of $dS$ it signifies a small surface,etc. What does it really mean?

Answer (score 3):

These quantities are all infinitesimals. $dx$ and $dl$ are often used to denote infinitesimal line elements, while $dS$ and $dA$ are conventionally used for infinitesimal surface (area) elements. The list is completed with $dV$, the infinitesimal volume element.

On the application of these infinitesimals: It is often simple and intuitive to think about integration as summing up infinitely many infinitesimally small contributions from surface ($dS$) or line ($dx$) elements, in a procedure that can be understood as the continuous analog of summation.

Comment: So,the main objective of using these  infinitesimals quantities is to use integration?

Comment: @user146181 In electrodynamics, yes.

Answer (score 0):

## Two dimensional case

Let's look at [Gauss's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law). The law says that if you have a surface $S$ which encloses a charge $Q_\textrm{enc}$, and there is an electric field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$ on the surface $S$, then the electric field and the charge enclosed are related by $Q_\textrm{enc} / \epsilon_0 = \iint_S \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot d\mathbf{A}$.

Now how should we think of the integral on the right hand side? It is supposed to represent the flux of electric field lines through the surface. Let's think about how the flux works for a planar surface.

[image]

If the surface is perpendicular to the field (the field is $\mathbf{B}$ in the picture), then the flux $\Phi$ is simply the product of the field strength and the area. If the field is not perpendicular to the surface, then there is a smaller flux. (Imagine the case where they are perpendicular, there would be no field lines actually passing through the surface.) The geometric factor that says how much smaller the flux gets when the field is tilted by an angle $\theta$ from being perpendicular is $\Phi = BA \cos \theta$. Now if we define the vector $\mathbf{A}$ to be the be vector whose magnitude is the area of the surface and whose direction is the normal to the surface, then the formula for the flux can be written concisely as $\Phi = \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{A}$.

Now the surface in Gauss's law will not be planar. Thus there is no well defined normal direction over the entire surface, and we cannot directly use the formula from the previous paragraph to find the flux. However, if we zoom in on a very small region of the surface, there will be a well-defined normal direction so we can make an area vector. This area vector will be called $d\mathbf{A}$. Notice that this area vector depends on where in the surface we zoomed in to. The $d$ is to remind us that we are looking at a small region. Now we can use the formula from the previous paragraph to get how much flux passes through this part of the surface $d\Phi =\mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{A}$. Here, both $\mathbf{E}$ and $d\mathbf{A}$ depend on where on the surface we are looking. Again we have used a $d$ in front of the $\Phi$ to indicate that the flux will be a small amount since it is only the flux through a tiny piece of the surface.

Now to get the total flux through the whole surface, we just sum up the flux through each of the tiny surface. Thus we get $\Phi = \iint_S d \Phi = \iint_S \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{A}$. Now it should be clear what $d\mathbf{A}$ is. It is a vector representing a small region of your surface. It represents the amount of area of that small region and it points the direction perpendicular to the surface in that region.

## One dimensional case

This same reasoning also comes up in one dimension. We know that if an object experiences a constant force $\mathbf{F}$ and moves by a displacement $\mathbf{r}$, then the work $W$ done is given by $W=\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{r}$. But what happens if the force isn't constant and the path is not straight? Then we can follow the same procedure where we zoom in on the path and calculate the work done over each small segment. The work $d W$ done over a small segment is given by $dW=\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is the force acting when the object is on that segment of the path and $d\mathbf{r}$ is a vector whose magnitude is the length of the small segment and direction is the direction the object moves when it travels through that segment. Then we can find the total work by adding up the work done over each little segment $W = \int dW = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$. So here $d\mathbf{r}$ is just a small vector whose magnitude is the length of the segment of a path and whose direction is the direction the object as it moves through that segment of the path.

## Symbols

Now I have explained what the surface element $d\mathbf{A}$ and the line element $d \mathbf{r}$ are. But you mentioned another symbol in your question: $d \mathbf{S}$. This is because there are other symbols that can be used interchangeably with $d\mathbf{A}$, the same way you could use $\mathbf{x}$ or $\mathbf{r}$ to represent a position in 3d. Another symbol for an infinitessimal you might see is $d\mathbf{\Sigma}$. There are also several symbols that can be used in place of $d \mathbf{r}$. Some of them are $d \mathbf{x}$, $d \mathbf{s}$, and $d \mathbf{l}$